# polynomial residue: $(z+3)^2\sin\left(\frac{z + y + 1}{(z + 3)^3}\right)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a complex function f(z), one way to find the residue at a pole is to find the Laurent series centered at that pole since the coefficient for the term with exponent of negative 1 is  the residue of the pole. If the 'coefficient' for the term with exponent of negative 1 is a polynomial in z that can be evaluated at the pole, will that be my residue? Or do I need to try another method for finding the residue? For example:

> If $f(z) = (z+3)^2\sin\left(\dfrac{z + y + 1}{(z + 3)^3}\right)$, Then the Laurent series centered around $-3$ is

$f(z) = (z+3)^2\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (z + y + 1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)! (z +3)^{6n+3}} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (z + y + 1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)! (z +3)^{6n+1}} $

So the coefficient of the term with exponent -1 is (z + y + 1). Then is the residue of f(z) at -3 equal to (-3 + 0 + 1) = -2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a Laurent series.  A Laurent series centred at $z=p$ must be of the form $\sum_j c_j (z-p)^j$ where the $c_j$ are constants (i.e. they can't depend on $z$).

But what you can say is that the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=-3$ is
the sum over $n$ of the residues of $g_n(z) = (-1)^n (z + y + 1)^{2n+1}/((2n+1)! (z+3)^{6n+1}$ at $z=-3$.  For convenience write $z = -3 + t$ so you're looking at powers of $t$. 
We have $g_n(z) = \dfrac{(-1)^n (y-2+t)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!\; t^{6n+1}}$.
Expanding $(y - 2 + t)^{2n+1}$, the highest power of $t$ that appears is $t^{2n+1}$, so for $n \ge 1$ there is no $t^{-1}$ term in it and the residue is $0$.  For $n=0$ we have $g_0(z) = \dfrac{y-2}{t} + 1$, and the residue is $y-2$.

Comment: Since we are evaluating $g_0(z)$ at the pole z = -3 + 0i (or t = 0 + 0i), can we simplify the residue to y-2 = 0-2 = -2?

Comment: $y$ can't be the imaginary part of $z$ in this context: that would make $f$ non-analytic, and there would be no such thing as a residue.  I considered it to be a separate parameter.